# Using google cloud only for database

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform

I am having a large website that struggling a bit, uptime not great and speed as well, and there is a lot of load on it. I am thinking of moving into google cloud but I don't have time to manage the server and become the host.

So my idea is to just serve the database from google cloud (so I can benefit from the auto-scale) and leave the website files where they are now.

My question is: Will that put less load on the cpu? and will it eventually improve the website uptime?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to your question, I think yes it will help you to improve website performance but you will see a big jump in the performance because of the database utilize more CPU and ram in the server and when you provide a separate machine for the database it will increase performance but if you want to decrease website loading time then there are other services which I suggest you services like [Cloudflare][1] or any CDN it will help you and you can use web server optimization techniques.

You can use Google CloudSQL Service if you are using MySQL or Postgres Database. Else you can use Google Compute Engine VM which you have to manage. If you want a complete website auto-scaling option I would suggest you can go with Google App Engine by which you can easily do auto-scale companies like many well-funded startups.

```
https://www.cloudflare.com/  
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs
https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move your data to [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/), I highly recommend using Cloud SQL. If budget is not an issue, auto-scaling would be advantageous.

Will that put less load on the cpu?

- Most likely it will, since your taking away the database processes on your server.

You may also want to look into using Google App Engine connected to Cloud Sql in the same [region](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/) will have less latency.